# Fragments : Manage data until not signup

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragments which is settled in `TabLayout` with `ViewPager`.

[image]

The Scenario is:

- First fragment has one `ImageView` with some `EditText` and `RadioButton` with **NEXT** Button
- Second fragment has 5 `EditText` with **NEXT** Button
- Third Fragment has 4 `ImageView` and 4 `EditText` with **SignUp** Button

all fields are required.

Now what I have done:

1. Checked all validation on Button click of Fragment 1 and moved to NEXT fragment.

   ```
   if (getActivity() != null) {
       ((RegisterActivity) getActivity()).mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
   }
   ```
2. Same process
3. Same process and proceed for **SignUp.**

## Problem:

- How can I check values When I move to second fragment without clicking button (Sliding Viewpager or Clicking on TAB)
- How can I update all final values (when I change it but do not click on button and move forward)

I have tried to use **onAttach** and **onDetach** for saving values but didn't worked.

**Any solution for manage all data and check validation in each situation?**

Comment: Sir may be using [Share data between fragments with ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Comment: Try adding PageChangeListener https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener

Comment: Have you tried setUserVisibleHint?

Comment: did u solved it? Have u tried using `ViewModel`

Comment: I haven't tried but I will try soon and update you.

Answer (score 0):

You can track of current selected tab by `TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener`,
take a look here for more information [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener)
In general just implement this interface and then you will be notified when user swipe tabs or if you programmatically swipe you will still get notified.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but the workaround I have recently implemented.

- Take `boolean[]` of total fragments.

like:

```
private boolean[] arrLastPageDone = new boolean[]{false, false, false};
```

If all values of fragment1 validated, set `true` on first position. Same for other fragments.

- Simply check values in `onPageSelected.`

like:

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (position > 0 && !arrLastPageDone[position - 1]) {
                    pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

And it works. It dosen't let swipe to next fragment until all values validated.

[image: view_pager_restriction]

- And you can save those data to SingleTon Class until all process finished.